# How to change the Write Ahead Log directory on Windows

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging

On postgres 9.6 for Windows server 2008. How do I change the Write Ahead Log directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-internals.html)

> WAL logs are stored in the directory pg_wal under the data directory, as a set of segment files [...]

The docs go on to day,

> It is advantageous if the log is located on a different disk from the main database files. This can be achieved by moving the pg_wal directory to another location (while the server is shut down, of course) and creating a symbolic link from the original location in the main data directory to the new location.

So your options are simple on Windows

- [NTFS Symbolic Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), or ReFS symbolic links.
- Change the `data_directory`